# How to add a CSS class on HTML button via PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have registration form and I need to hide submit button. This button will be visible after action in PHP.

I tried to use CSS classes and it works, but I don't know how to add a class with PHP.

Here is button with class I want to change:

```
<form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform">
 <input type="submit" name="register" value="registrovat" id="button8" class=I don't know what /><br><br>
</form>
```

My CSS:

```
#button8{
    visibility: hidden;
    font-family: century gothic;
    color: #0099FF;
    border: 2px solid #0099FF;
    background: transparent;
}
#button8.visible{
    visibility: visible;}
```

I need to change to button8.visible but in PHP (I have condition depend on MySQL data).

**EDIT:**

I need it because, the button will be visible based on code. User put the code, press a button. This action will run PHP: connect to mySQL find if this code is in database. If yes I need my button to be visible. Because of my low knowledge, I want to use if condition in the same PHP session where is mySQL. Here is the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Panákovač 4.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>


</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>

<?php
// show potential errors / feedback (from registration object)
if (isset($registration)) {
    if ($registration->errors) {
        foreach ($registration->errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
    if ($registration->messages) {
        foreach ($registration->messages as $message) {
            echo $message;
        }
    }
}

?>

<!-- register form -->
<form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform">
    <input id="login_input_username" class="login_input" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,64}" name="user_name" placeholder="uživatelské jméno" required /><br>
    <input id="login_input_password_new" class="login_input" type="password" name="user_password_new" pattern=".{6,}" placeholder="heslo (min. 6 znaků)" required autocomplete="off" /><br>
    <input id="login_input_password_repeat" class="login_input" type="password" name="user_password_repeat" pattern=".{6,}" placeholder="zopakujte heslo" required autocomplete="off" /><br>
    <input id="login_input_firstname" class="login_input" type="text" name="user_firstname" placeholder="jméno" required /><br>
    <input id="login_input_lastname" class="login_input" type="text" name="user_lastname" placeholder="příjmení" required /><br>
    <input id="login_input_email" class="login_input" type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="e-mail" required /><br>
    <input id="login_input_company" class="login_input" type="text" name="user_company" placeholder="firma" required /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="registrovat" id="button8" class= /><br><br>
</form>

<form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform">
    <input id="login_input_code" class="login_input" type="text" name="user_code" placeholder="ověřovací kód" required /><br>
    <input type="submit"  name="kod" value="ověřit kód"/><br>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['kod'])){
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "login";


            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 
$user_code = $_POST['user_code'];
$sql = "SELECT `used`,`code` FROM `regcode` WHERE `code` LIKE '$user_code' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "kód: " . $row["code"]. " - použito: " . $row["used"]. $zob . "<br>";
        $pouzito = $row["used"];
MY CONDION FOR CLASSES
    }
} else {
    echo "chybný kód" . $user_code;
}
            $conn->close();
    }  

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use javascript? What you're trying to do doesn't exactly make sense

Comment: Use a conditional in php. Something like `<input class"<?= $condition ?
 'visible' : 'hidden'"> ?>`

Comment: It does make sense, but it would be simpler to just make the entire button conditional on the result of your MySQL result. If you want more help, we'll  need to see your PHP that retrieves this result.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Bellow is my whole code. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can add a php if condition inside the html content like this:

```
<form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform">
  <input type="submit" name="register" value="registrovat" id="button8" 
     class="<?php if(condition) { echo 'classname'; } ?>" />
</form>
```

In this case if the condition is `true` it will `echo` the class inside the class attribute, there are other ways to do it but this is the most intuitive way for new PHP developers.

Like @Jordi Nebot  told you can just do the short version like:

```
<input class="<?= ($condition) ? 'classname' : ''"> ?>
```

Comment: ye-eees ... but if all it's doing it toggling visibility, why output the `<input ... />` at all?

Comment: @CD001 True, but he is only asking how to add a class inside HTML content with php, I show him the best intuitive way because it looks he is learning how to :)

Answer (score 0):

only way in PHP is to echo the output

```
 echo '<input type="submit" name="register" value="registrovat" id="button8" 
 class="class1">';

 echo '<input type="submit" name="register" value="registrovat" id="button8" 
 class="class2">';
```

etc...

or

```
$class = "class1";
?>
input type="submit" name="register" value="registrovat" id="button8" 
 class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
<?php

$class = "class2";
?>
input type="submit" name="register" value="registrovat" id="button8" 
 class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
<?php
```

Comment: This doesn't actually address the conditional nature of the question.

Comment: sure it does, question was how to change class name in php. The only way to do that is the change the name in the output you echo

Comment: So... where's the condition?

Comment: Admittedly, it's not the clearest of questions, but you're not addressing how the OP would arrive at these two states.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $classname = condition ? 'class8' : 'defaultClass'; ?>
<form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform">
        <input type="submit" name="register" value="registrovat" id="button8" class="<?php echo $classname; ?>" /><br><br>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator like:

```
   <form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform">
      <input type="submit" name="register" value="registrovat" id="button8" class"<?= $condition ? 'classvisible' : 'classhidden'"?> />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I didn't know, that PHP has to be placed above HTML if i want to use variable from PHP.
IN PHP:

```
...//some condition
If ($row["used"] == 0){
        $myclass ="zobrazeno";
        }
...
```

In HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="register" value="registrovat" id="button8" class=<?php echo $myclass; ?> /><br><br>
```

In CSS:

```
#button8{
    visibility: hidden;
    font-family: century gothic;
    color: #0099FF;
    border: 2px solid #0099FF;
    background: transparent;

#button8.zobrazeno{
    visibility: visible;
```